# When should I implement actions as Behavior Tree (BT)?

Tags: ros-melodic, action-server

I have an action called *take_pallet*, implemented by BT, which has several actions like: `MoveToPoint`, `Docking`, `Lifting`...

Currently, the `Lifting` action only lift the pallet up or down. But now, I want to add more complex logic for Lifting action, like check the height, add timeout, feedback status...

I wonder if I should implement this action using BT or just a simple ROS action and handle all the logic business inside execute_cb() function.

I would prefer the second option, since using BT may improve reusability and you won't have to rebuild your code if something change in the BT script, but I will have to define more BT node like `HeightChecking` node, `TimeOut` node... which will time consuming and maybe I won't reuse those action nodes.

Any rules or guidelines for this situation? At which control level should I use BT for robotics applications?

Edit: I'm using BehaviorTreeCpp v3.8 by Davide Faconti. [github](https://github.com/BehaviorTree/BehaviorTree.CPP/tree/v3.8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on section `3.7. Choosing the Proper Granularity of a BT` from the book **Behavior Trees in Robotics and AI: An Introduction** of Michele Colledanchise and Petter Ögren, I have some criteria to consider when I want to apply BT for actions:

- If sub-behaviors of the action always executed in the exact order then implement it as a Leaf node.
- If sub-behaviors of the action can be devided and can be reused if other places, then implement it as a sub-BT.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding, the behavior tree is designed to create intuitive user experiences. Therefore, it seems unnecessary for the end user to be concerned with technical details like timeouts or HeightChecking. A more effective approach might be to parameterize these steps within your Lifting Action Server. This would allow you to pass specific parameters to the action node when it is invoked within your behavior tree.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have found a solution and posted it.